# Carousel Thumbnails still not auto updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Building a carousel with thumbnails, the thumbnail should correspond with the slide displayed and the selected thumbnail should have a border around it to let users know which slide they are on. My current code just has the thumbnails selected onclick they should be auto updating with each slide of the carousel, what have I done wrong?

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
interval: 4000
});

// handles the carousel thumbnails
$('.carousel-selector').click(function () {
var selectorIdx = $(this).closest('li').index();

$('#myCarousel')
  .carousel(selectorIdx)
  .find('.carousel-selector').removeClass('selected')
  .eq(selectorIdx).addClass('selected')
  .end()
  .find('.item').removeClass('selected')
  .eq(selectorIdx).addClass('active');
});
```

Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/gward90/xr8qzxmg/9/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to go about this is to use the `slide.bs.carousel` event to change the "active" thumbnail.

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 4000
});

var selectorIdx = 1;
var numItems = $('.carousel-selector').length;

// handles the carousel thumbnails
$('.carousel-selector').click(function () {
    selectorIdx = $(this).closest('li').index();
    $('#myCarousel').carousel(selectorIdx)
});

$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
    $('#myCarousel')
        .find('.carousel-selector').removeClass('selected')
        .eq(selectorIdx).addClass('selected')
        .end()
        .find('.item').removeClass('selected')
        .eq(selectorIdx).addClass('active');
    if (selectorIdx < (numItems - 1))
        selectorIdx++;
    else
        selectorIdx = 0;
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xr8qzxmg/16/)

Comment: @imtheman thank you is there a way to do this without declaring the number of slides? This carousel structure applys to many pages. The number of slides may vary with each project.

Comment: You can replace `var numItems = 12;` with `var numItems = $('.carousel-selector').length;`